# WebSocketSubject - Advantage?

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

Disclaimer: I'm new to web development so bear with me...

Stack: Angular front-end, Tornado (python-based) web server for back end

I've been using RxJs and WebSocket successfully to communicate with the backend, based on this very popular tutorial:  https://medium.com/@lwojciechowski/websockets-with-angular2-and-rxjs-8b6c5be02fac

I've just stumbled on WebSocketSubject in RxJs 5 and I'm wondering what the advantages are?

So far, I've been able to use it to connect, send and receive, but I can't figure out how to use the typical RxJs operators that I get with a Subject... so in a way it just seems harder to use.

What am I missing?

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
  //create the socket
  this.pubsubSubject = WebSocketSubject.create("ws://" + this.hostName + ":" + connection_info.port + "/" + connection_info.ps);

  //output a message when it's open
  this.pubsubSubject.openObserver = {
    next: value => {
      console.log("ps socket is " + (this.pubsubSubject.socket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN ? "OPEN" : "NOT OPEN"));
    }
  }

  //send the authentication token through the socket
  this.pubsubSubject.next(JSON.stringify(authenticate_request));

//subscribe to specific events from server
var subscription = {
  "subscribe": events
}
this.pubsubSubject.next(JSON.stringify(subscription));

//start getting messages
this.pubsubSubject.subscribe(
  (msg: any) => {
    console.log("msg: " + msg);
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think my confusion comes from a lack of understanding of RxJs fundamentals.  But, I did figure out how to map in this case, as follows:

```
  this.pubsubSubject
    .map((resp: IPubSubMessage): any => {
      console.log(resp.payload);

    }).subscribe();
```

For those needing more information on WebSocketSubject in particular, you might look at the comments in the code, here:

https://github.com/mpodlasin/rxjs/blob/47ae8573256609492e16a957348883f0c8039c2e/src/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.ts

I couldn't find this detail anywhere else, so this may be the best place to look for now.

Happy to have others chime in with more information though.